# SilverStripe 3: Load/Create page outside of the CMS

Tags: silverstripe

is it possible to create a page outside of the cms?

For example:

I would like to use jquery .load() to load a segment into a current page.

Is it possible to create a html or .ss file somewhere in the theme folder eg: self-contained-page.html so if I then visit www.domain.com/self-contained-paged.html I will be able to visit this page.

Answer (score 2):

While you can of course serve static files, you can also "ajaxify" parts of your page. Not sure if that's what you want to do, but in case someone else is trying to do something similar.

While you could use some fancy tools like [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) or [history.js](https://gist.github.com/balupton/854622), you can also do it manually. I've recently done this with SS 2.4, but SS 3 should be pretty similar:

In your controller, add a public function so you can access it via /yourpage/load (or whatever you want to call it):

```
   public function load(){
       return $this->renderWith(array('AjaxLoad'));
   }
```

In your templates/Layout add a file AjaxLoad.ss.

- If you only want to serve that page via your jQuery `.load()`, simply add the content right inside the file.
- If you want to use the piece of content both on your regular page and want to replace it with the ajaxified version, use `<% include PageSnippet %>` both on the general and the ajaxified page. Then simply define your content in *templates/Include/PageSnippet.ss*.

You can see it in action at http://www.contentaward.at/content-lab-vienna/608#details (click on the small images at the bottom of the page). Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: nice tooltip hover effect in your example ;)

Comment: it's always the least important stuff that gets most attention ;)

Comment: ...because it _does_ make a difference!

Answer (score 1):

there is no problem with serving static html files from anywhere in your silverstripe installation, just note to always add the file extension to your urls, as otherwise silverstripe's url routing (using mod_rewrite, see the .htaccess file) will kick in.

also note to always use the full path to the file, so in case you placed your file in 'themes/mytheme/test.html' the url will be 'http://www.domain.com/themes/mytheme/test.html'

Answer (score 0):

You can of course reference a html file in the theme folder just as you would do with a css file, f.e. :

> www.domain.com/themes/yourtheme/self-contained-paged.html

If you dont mind to not have it in the theme folder you can also place it into root dir.
Or you can modify your .htaccess and apply some mod_rewrite or redirect rules to point into the theme folder.

If you want to use .ss files you probably have to use CMS pages.